# Getting error while merge duplicate constituents in HEDA version

Tags: apex, error, master-detail

I am facing issue while merging the constituents in HEDA. I am new to Salesforce so I don't know how to start. Can anyone please help me with that issue.

**HEDA**: Higher Education Data Architecture - AppExchange Managed Package that runs on the Salesforce platform.

While merging duplicate constituents (Contacts) I am getting 
"Record cannot be deleted because children records exist. Delete children first." Shouldn't child records automatically delete while deleting master record if its a parent child relationship.?

Comment: Sinner could you please provide some more details ? Eg: what is HEDA ? how is this question related to salesforce communities or scheduled apex ?

Comment: @sinner - There could be a trigger in place that prevents you from doing so which is most likely the case as you are correct, under standard configuration deletion of a Master record deletes the children as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[update] I found a solution for this. See just below the struck-out section

I was able to duplicate this error in a new Developer Environment I created to test this issue. I had to install the HEDA managed package first. I then went to merge two contacts under the same account and this error popped up - Record cannot be deleted because children records exist. Delete children first.

I had to delete the Affiliated Accounts from the victim contact which was being merged. Then the merge worked to the survivor contact. The screenshot from the new DE org I created shows the record I had to delete for the merge to go through

[image]

<strike>Given that this is a managed package, there isn't much we can do to fix this ourself. Your best bet would be to delete the related list records and try again. Hopefully this is only a few records for you.</strike>

With further investigation I found this as a possible solution

1. Click on the tab Trigger Handlers
2. select the view All-Main Fields
3. click on the row with the trigger class named CON_CannotDelete_TDTM
4. When the Trigger Handler window opens, click Edit
5. deselect the active flag and Save
6. Perform the mergers now
7. Once done, remember to set it back to Active
   [image]
   [image]

For people who were asking about it - HEDA stands for Salesforce's Higher Education Data Architecture available from Salesforce.org. You can install it as a managed package from [AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000DpyghEAB)

Comment: Thank you, @Anil for providing this detail answer for the whole community. Two small things to add: 1 there is additional class that does similar validation for account named ACCT_CannotDelete_TDTM. 2 HEDA is also an open-source project, and the source code can be seen at https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/HEDAP. If you search for the error string there you can see where it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Shout out of thanks to [@Anil](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/10960/anil) and [@ceiroa](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/385/ceiroa) !

Had I started by searching for the exact error string, I could have saved hours of puzzling.
For the next guy, mine was stuck on ACCT_CannotDelete_TDTM as @ceiroa suggested.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.